# Error 404 objecto no encontrado al subir imagen a mi servidor xampp

Tags: php, mysql

soy nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo y con este post me estreno en esta maravillosa página. Ahí va mi problema:

Estoy desarrollando una web para el proyecto de fin de ciclo, y estoy utilizando xampp en ubuntu 18.04, al  intentar subir una foto a mi servidor me tira este error:

adjunto el código también, ahora mismo el código es pobre puesto que solo quiero que se suba para ya después ponerle todos los posibles errores y demas. Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: error]

[image: código]

Comment: bienvenido a **SOes**, por favor edita tu pregunta y pon tu código en texto en vez de imagen. También agrega el código del formulario, porque lo más seguro es que ahí es donde está el error; el código `404` lo obtienes cuando no se encuentra la página y no por errores al procesarla.

Comment: Efectivamente ahí estaba el error, estaba mal la ruta del action, ya está solucionado, para el próximo post ya sabre lo del código en texto, he pecado de novato, muchas gracias por tu respuesta!